# Selecting 10-Character Password - Probability of at least three digits

Tags: probability

Can anyone help me understand if my process of solving this problem is correct and whether I can make any improvements? (Sorry about formatting, still learning syntax)

Suppose that you generate a 10-character password by selecting each character independently and uniformly at random from $\{\texttt{a},\texttt{b},\ldots,\texttt{z}\}\cup \{\texttt{A},\texttt{B},\ldots,\texttt{Z}\}\cup\{\texttt{0},\texttt{1},\ldots,\texttt{9}\}$. What is the probability that at least three of the characters are digits?

My Answer:

Assuming each of the 62 possible characters are equally likely to be selected, the probability of selecting a digit character is 10/62. Assuming each character is selected independently from the other, the problem may be modeled by the binomial distribution, which describes the probability of getting k successes in a run of n trials with a probability p of getting a success in each trial. In this case, where a success is getting a digit character, the probability of getting exactly k successes is equal to :

$\binom{10}{k}\left (\frac{10}{62}\right )^{k}\left ( \frac{52}{62}\right )^{10-k}$

But since we are trying to solve the probability that at least three of the characters are digits, we can find the probabilities of getting 0, 1, and 2 successes respectively and subtract from 1 to obtain our answer. The steps are shown below:

1 - $\sum_{k = 0}^{2}\binom{10}{k}\left (\frac{10}{62}\right )^{k}\left ( \frac{52}{62}\right )^{10-k}$\
= 1 - ((1(1)$(52/62)^{10})$ + ((10(10/62)$(52/62)^{9})$ + ((45$(10/62)^{2}$$(52/62)^{8})$
= 1 - (.17 + .33 + .28) 
= .22

The probability that at least three of the characters are digits is approximately .22.

Comment: The strategy is correct.  However, you should not round until the final step.  When I put the same numbers into a [calculator](https://www.desmos.com/scientific), I obtain $0.21$ to two decimal places.